# Passing through JS variables onchange

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass through three variables (`artistID`, `albumID` and currently selected value) to function player but I keep getting an error each time I try this:

```
var carry_else = 'actorID,movieID,this.value'
```

This is the code as it stands I have been trying to edit `var carry_else` to no success:

```
actorID = movie_select.substring(0, movie_select.indexOf(':'));
movieID = movie_select.substring(movie_select.indexOf(':')+1, movie_select.length); 

// this line needs to be edited to var carry_else = 'actorID,movieID,this.value' but doing this doesn't work    
var carry_else = 'this.value,this.value,this.value' 
hstr+="<form><select size='"+count+"' onChange='parent.info(" + carry_else + ");'>";
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: One way would be to not build your HTML with JavaScript, and certainly don't add JavaScript event handlers inline in HTML *that's inline* in JavaScript. [Here's a tutorial I found.](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domevent1.shtml)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I would like to try it with the code above and the hopefully expand into the tutorial. Is it not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since actorID and movieID appear to be strings, why not put them in as literals:

```
function escapeHtml(str) {
  return str.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/"/g,'&quot;');
};
function quoteString(str) {
  return '"'+str.replace(/"/g,'\\"')+'"';
}

hstr+="<form><select size='"+count+"' onChange='parent.info("+escapeHtml(quoteString(actorID))+","+escapeHtml(quoteString(movieID))+",this.value);'>";
```

If available, I'd use `JSON.stringify()` instead of the `quoteString` function I put above.

Comment: Can I also use `var carry_else = 'movie_select.substring(0, movie_select.indexOf(':')),movie_select.substring(movie_select.indexOf(':')+1, movie_select.length),this.value'`?

Comment: Only if movie_select is in the global scope.  And if you are OK with putting things in the global scope you could just do 'actorID,movieID,this.value'.  But I would not recommend polluting the global scope.  For one thing, that would break if you have more than one of these forms.

Comment: Whenever I try I get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: actorID is not defined` error!

Comment: That would be a sign that you didn't put it in the global scope.

Comment: When I try `carry = "movie_select.substring(0, movie_select.indexOf('/')), movie_select.substring(album_select.indexOf('/')+1, movie_select.length), this.value";` I get an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` error!

Comment: To clarify, I can't stress enough that global scope is a bad idea.  But if you are crazy enough to try it, use `window.actorID = ...` and `'window.actorID,...'`.

Comment: the token error I can't help you with since you didn't post the code with the '}' token in it.  Anyway that's getting outside the scope of this Question.